# CSP causing problems with .net core react app, failing to load resources?

Tags: asp.net-core, react-redux, styles, content-security-policy

I have a .net core 3.1 react template app set up.

I have added csp to the app like so:

[image]

The front end react application when trying to load styles for material ui i get the following errors:

[image]

how do i stop the CSP from blocking these resources?

i do not want to allow unsafe inline.

I am using https://github.com/juunas11/aspnetcore-security-headers
for the backed CSP implementation, I assumed that .FromSelf() would be enough as i have installed the node module for material-ui-react.

Comment: That may because your `jss.esm.js` contains other site css.Find the css url and add `From("xxx");` to your `csp.AllowStyles.FromSelf().`.

Comment: Where do i find this file, i don't seem to be able to find it.@Rena

Answer (score 0):

Content Security Policy considers as inline styles:

- **< tag style=...>**
- **< style>...< /style>**
- **Document.createElement('style')** via script
- **Element.setAttribute('styles')**  via script

CSP does not consider as inline style some CSS manipulations via script:

- **HTMLElement.style** i.e. *el.style.backgroundColor = 'gray';*
- **CSSStyleSheet.insertRule()**
- **CSSGroupingRule.insertRule()**
- **CSSStyleDeclaration.cssText** i.e. *el.style.cssText = 'color:blue; background-color:#fff;'*

If you do not want to allow 'unsafe-inline' in the *style-src* directive, you have to modify code or use external styles constructs:

- **< link href=>**
- **@import**
- **Link: < file.css >; rel=stylesheet** style binding via HTTP header